# emoticons are overlapping in UILabel

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios

I am ussing my customFont for Cmment Label but when I am adding emoticons then they are overlapping or cutting.I am using "HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn" Font.Please suggest any solution,

[image]

Comment: Why not use a uitextview?

Comment: I am displaying comments here,in UILabel and for comment I adding I am using UITextView.

Comment: Why not use a UITextView to display comments and disable editing? UITextView it's way more powerful than the label.

Comment: Yes,I solved issue using UITextView,thanks @Andrei.